# X-axis ticks (label) are not displaying properly as dates

Tags: jqplot

I have a graph like in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bqE7H/
I want to display the X-axis labels as dates like nov 1, nov 7, nov 13 in place of
1.0, 7.0, 13.0. I have tried using `dateAxesrenderer` but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is very confusing but the big issue I see is that your data arrays ln0 and ln1 do not have any date values:

```
ln0 = [68,7860,47,59,65,58,54,60,54,64,70,54,52,47,51,49,59,46,50,52,42,36,40,47,49,64];
ln1 = [30,27,45,36,42,37,32,33,30,37,44,42,66,77,64,68,83,81,102,65,70,52,53,73,57,58,58,47,47,48];
```

These need to be specified as point pairs:

```
ln0 = [['2011-11-01 12:00PM',68],['2011-11-02 12:00PM',68], etc...
```